# Hard work is "washed away" - Correct word?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to tell my boss that -

"*My hard work is always **washed away** by client's repetitive changes. Other employees' hard work is visible to you, but not mine. So everyone here got increment in the last 7 months but not me.*"

What is the correct word which can replace ***washed away*** and  please correct me if there is any better way to express the above point.

Comment: Explain further, please?

Comment: @dockeryZ : Client requirements always change in a week or two and i had to start afresh with my work. So my boss can't see my the hardwork I put in my work . I want to make this point to ask for a raise

Comment: I would mention and explain what would happen **without your unnoticed** work.

Comment: You might consider asking about this on the workplace stackexchange as well.

Comment: You could say that "my work would be more efficiently utilized if <this and that> would not keep happening". Then you switch the focus from talking about your emotions to informing about management of a company resource.

Comment: wiped out; turned to nothing; set aside; negated; invalidated; undone; set at naught; devalued

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use ***wasted*** for a single word:

> My hard work is always ***wasted*** by the client's repetitive changes.

Actually, the phrase **down the drain** is literally and figuratively close to your term **washed away** and means **wasted**.

> My hard work is/goes always ***down the drain*** due to the client's repetitive changes.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[down the drain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down-the-drain)**:
>
> If work or money is or goes **down the drain**, it is spoiled or
> **wasted**:
>
> If the factory closes, that will be a million dollars' worth of
> investment down the drain.
>
> **[wasted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wasted)** *adjective* (BADLY USED): ​
>
> Wasted time, money, etc. is time, money, etc. that is not used effectively because it does not
> produce the result you wanted:
>
> He wasn't in when I got there, so it was a completely wasted journey.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but if the word 'goes' is used, the sentence should begin with "my hard work always goes" rather than "my hard work goes always".

Answer (score 8):

How about **nullified**? There are two definitions of nullify in most of the online dictionaries and most of them are similar to this :

1 make legally null and void; invalidate.

2 make of no use or value; cancel out.

It seems to me that the second definition carries the meaning you are looking for.

See the Oxford online entry http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nullify

Comment: This is the only decent answer so far. All the others miss the point.

Answer (score 7):

*"My hard work always **goes unnoticed**..."*

***Unnoticed*** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unnoticed)

> *adjective, adverb* Without being seen or noticed
>   *"His contribution did not go unnoticed."*

***Escape notice*** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/escape+notice)

> *Fig.* to go unnoticed; not to have been noticed. (Usually a way to point out that someone has failed to see or respond to something.)
>   *"I suppose my earlier request escaped your notice, so I'm writing again."*
>   *"I'm sorry. Your letter escaped my notice."*

Answer (score 4):

How about **erased**, **obliterated**, **destroyed**, or **ruined**?

> "My hard work is always [**erased**, **obliterated**, **destroyed**, or
>   **ruined**] by client's repetitive changes. Other employees' hard work is visible to you, but not mine. So everyone here got increment in the
>   last 7 months but not me."

From Dictionary.com:

> **erase**: to obliterate
>
> **obliterate**: to remove or destroy all traces of; do away with; destroy completely.
>
> **destroy**: to reduce (an object) to useless fragments, a useless form, or remains, to render ineffective or useless; nullify;
>   neutralize; invalidate
>
> **ruin**: to injure (a thing) irretrievably

As to the lack of an "increment" compared to other employees, perhaps their work is not **washed away**, **erased**, **obliterated**, **destroyed**, or **ruined** by client's repetitive changes to the same extent as is the OP's.

Comment: *Erased*  fits the OP's sentence to a T.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *[obscured](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/obscure)* (the verb form)

> 1 Keep from being seen; conceal:
>   *gray clouds obscure the sun*
>
> 1.1 Make unclear and difficult to understand:
>   *the debate has become obscured by conflicting ideological perspectives*
>
> 1.2 Overshadow:
>   *none of this should obscure the skill, experience, and perseverance of the workers*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 3):

**Undercut** - bit more of an aggressive connotation.

You could also state your efforts are **offset** or **invalidated**.

Comment: Hi Benediah, welcome to English Language & Usage. You'll notice that all the other answers provide a dictionary definition for their proposed solution. This is an expectation on our site; short answers without any supporting evidence can be viewed as merely comments or opinion, which undermines EL&U's aim to build "a library of detailed answers to every question about English language and usage." You can add more detail by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let me toss in my suggestion...

> My hard work is always **made useless** by the client's repetitive changes.

I feel like "wasted" wouldn't be a good word to use here; that would imply that the client is somehow *consuming* your work in a wasteful manner. Likewise, "destroyed" and "ruined" don't really make sense unless the client is actually changing your work. The phrase "goes unnoticed" makes it sound like the *only* problem is that your boss doesn't pay attention to your work.

(By the way, is it possible for you to do the work in a way that is more resistant to changing requirements?)